# What is the 'override' keyword in C++ used for?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I am a beginner in C++. I have come across `override` keyword used in the header file that I am working on. May I know, what is real use of `override`, perhaps with an example would be easy to understand.

Comment: Note also c++11 introduced the `final` keyword.

Comment: @JesseGood and again: `final` __also is not a keyword__ !!!

Comment: @zaufi it's a [contextual keyword](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#override)

Comment: It's something inspired from Java's `@Override` to let compiler do the compile time  checking for you

Answer (score 493, accepted):

The `override` keyword serves two purposes:

1. It shows the reader of the code that "this is a virtual method, that is overriding a virtual method of the base class."
2. The compiler also knows that it's an override, so it can "check" that you are not altering/adding new methods that you think are overrides.

To explain the latter:

```cpp
class base
{
  public:
    virtual int foo(float x) = 0; 
};


class derived: public base
{
   public:
     int foo(float x) override { ... } // OK
};

class derived2: public base
{
   public:
     int foo(int x) override { ... } // ERROR
};
```

In `derived2` the compiler will issue an error for "changing the type". Without `override`, at most the compiler would give a warning for "you are hiding virtual method by same name".

Comment: shouldn't the function header for* foo* be similar in class *derived2* ?? I compiled this with VS2017 and got a compile error. I mean that in*derived2* *foo's* header must be: *int foo ( float x) override {...} *

Comment: Uhm, that's entirely the point, the code example shows how override can be used to detect an error!

Comment: I think #3 is that override can be used to detect the to-be-overridden function (belonging to the parent class/interface) is removed (not alternated).  This is useful if the subclass is expecting a callback but it will never happen due to the library change, etc.

Comment: I don't think the compiler can do that without scanning all of the call-graph, and if the compiler does that, it won't need `override` to understand that. It's really hard to achieve that.

Answer (score 90):

And as an addendum to all answers, FYI: `override` **is not a keyword**, but a *special* kind of identifier! It has meaning only in the context of declaring/defining virtual functions, in other contexts it's just an ordinary **identifier**. For details read 2.11.2 of *The Standard*.

```
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct derived : base
{
    virtual void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    base* override = new derived();
    override->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
zaufi@gentop /work/tests $ g++ -std=c++11 -o override-test override-test.cc
zaufi@gentop /work/tests $ ./override-test
virtual void derived::foo()
```

Comment: It works (here and for `final`) because you can't use regular identifiers where these contextual keywords would be placed.

Comment: why the hell it's not forbidden?

Comment: @FerencDajka 1. Why should it be? 2. Suddenly adding a new keyword (i.e. forbidding the use of it everywhere else) would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: ordinal or ordinary ?

Comment: What is "The Standard"? Google has zillions of things called "Standard"... Link please?

Comment: @krubo https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard The word "standard" refers to something that is officially agreed upon internationally. For example, the definition of how long a meter is is a standard

Answer (score 13):

`override` is a C++11 keyword which means that a method is an "override" from a method from a base class. Consider this example:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void func1();
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void func1() override;
};
```

If `B::func1()` signature doesn't equal `A::func1()` signature a compilation error will be generated because `B::func1()` does not override `A::func1()`, it will define a new method called `func1()` instead.

Comment: According to C++ specification, "override" is an "identifier with special meaning". But such things in C# are called contextual keywords.

Comment: I think there's someting incorrect in this snippet. For the compiler to issue an error, the signature in Bar, the derived class, would have to be different, as in `void func1(int v) override;` in order for the compiler to issue an error like `marked 'override', but does not override. IOW: Oddly enough, the override seems a hint for the compiler to use in the derived class, to verify that the same signature exists in the base. See [Mats Petersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198377/1724025) answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says:

> Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes.

In detail, when you have an object foo that has a void hello() function:

```cpp
class foo {
    virtual void hello(); // Code : printf("Hello!");
};
```

A child of foo, will also have a hello() function:

```cpp
class bar : foo {
    // no functions in here but yet, you can call
    // bar.hello()
};
```

However, you may want to print "Hello Bar!" when hello() function is being called from a bar object. You can do this using override

```cpp
class bar : foo {
    virtual void hello() override; // Code : printf("Hello Bar!");
};
```

Comment: You don't need the override identifier to do this in C++, it simply enforces that you are doing it properly.

Comment: Hi, indeed the wikipedia concept is good as a general basis, but as Goose mentions, the specifics of C++ add a twist: It's used in the derived class to help the compiler identify issues in your code, in this case, that the virtual function exists in the base. The devil is in the details. See [Marks Petersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198377/1724025) comment above.