# Does final imply override?

Tags: c++, overriding, final, virtual-functions

As I understand it, the `override` keyword states that a given declaration implements a base `virtual` method, and the compilation should fail if there is no matching base method found.

My understanding of the `final` keyword is that it tells the compiler that no class shall override this `virtual` function.

So is `override final` redundant? [It seems to compile fine](http://ideone.com/9V7zNx). What information does `override final` convey that `final` does not? What is the use case for such a combination?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`final` does not require the function to override anything in the first place. Its effect is defined in [class.virtual]/4 as

> If a virtual function `f` in some class `B` is marked with the
>   *virt-specifier* `final` and in a class `D` derived from `B` a function `D::f`
>   overrides `B::f`, the program is ill-formed.

That's it. Now `override final` would simply mean
„This function overrides a base class one (`override`) and cannot be overriden itself (`final`).“
`final` on it's own would impose a weaker requirement.
`override` and `final` have independent behavior.

---

Note that `final` can only be used for virtual functions though - [class.mem]/8

> A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in the declaration of a
>   virtual member function (10.3).

Hence the declaration

```
void foo() final;
```

Is effectively the same as

```
virtual void foo() final override;
```

Since both require `foo` to override something - the second declaration by using `override`, and the first one by being valid if and only if `foo` is implicitly virtual, i.e. **when `foo` is overriding a virtual function called `foo` in a base class, which makes `foo` in the derived one automatically virtual.**  Thus `override` would be superfluous in declarations where `final`, but not `virtual`, occurs.
Still, the latter declaration expresses the intent a lot clearer and should definitely be preferred.

Comment: I like your answer, but I'd like to clarify that from a practical point of view `virtual void f() final override` and `void f() final` are equivalent in the sense that both of them fail if they do not override something. `final` is only valid for virtual functions and the latter declaration of `f` is only virtual if it overrides a function. Error messages for the latter one may be less precise though.

Comment: *the latter declaration expresses the intent a lot clearer* - I don't think so. Your description has led me to **prefer the first declaration style** for the same reason I'd avoid to add `virtual` when overriding a virtual method: it adds no value. But it's of course better than writing `virtual void foo() final;`

Comment: @Wolf You don't think it expresses the intent clearer? Could you articulate exactly what the intent is that is expressed by the first declaration form?

Comment: I think `final` *has to* be `virtual` after your description (I'm just learning these new features) and since you omit the `virtual` keyword, it wouldn't compile if it was not an `override`. Or maybe I am overlooking a case that could lead to unwanted behaviour? The use of non-overriding final virtual I'm just trying to figure out below [Angew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412516/2932052) ...

Comment: I should add that bot variants you list in your answer are clear concerning their intent, only `virtual void foo() final;` would be unclear.

Comment: @Wolf If I regard the first line lexically, all I can immediately discern is that it cannot be overriden. The fact that `final` implies the function must be virtual to begin with is language-specific and not even that well-known, so the first line doesn't express its intent in a manner equally comprehensible and language-agnostic as the second one's.

Comment: I have to admit that I have to get used to it first. Just one note, wouldn't it be better to suggest writing `void foo() final override;` to show intent clearly without introducing redundancies?

Comment: @Wolf IMO the `virtual` keyword is not redundant at all. According to your argument, `override` is just as redundant, and you seem to concede that it is not, at least not in the context of expressiveness.

Comment: Most likely that is the reason why e. g. the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Inheritance) suggests to "annotate overrides of virtual functions or virtual destructors with exactly one of an **override or (less frequently) final specifier**. Do not use virtual when declaring an override".

Comment: Clang-tidy has a check (modernize-use-override) that complains when you use both override and final.

Comment: in the case where there is no base class method, the couple compilers I tried `void f() final` complains the function is not virtual, whereas `void f() final override` complains that there is not a method being overridden (and sometimes that the method is not virtual). `override` is most commonly used to catch errors with base class methods changing. In this case, we would want the error that comes with `final override` as a dev unfamiliar with the code might 'fix' the error by adding virtual to the method, instead of updating the method to match the signature in the base class.

Answer (score 25):

`final` does not necessarily imply that the function is overridden. It's perfectly valid (if of somewhat dubious value) to declare a virtual function as `final` on its *first* declaration in the inheritance hierarchy.

One reason I can think of to create a virtual and immediately final function is if you want to *prevent* a derived class from giving the same name & parameters a different meaning.

Comment: +1 For showing a feasible use-case of a virtual/immediately-final function.  I wonder if the compiler still generates a vtable when this is done though?

Comment: @Carlton That's up to the compiler. As far as the standard is concerned, it makes the class polymorphic, however - which means `dynamic_cast` must work for it, for example. I believe vtable implementations of virtual functions also need the vtable to make `dynamic_cast` work.

Comment: Bahh, I just posted a question based on my previous comment, but you pretty much just answered it here.  Thanks.

Comment: If *you want to prevent a derived class from giving the same name & parameters a different meaning*, don't make it a virtual method. I don't see a *feasible use-case* in this vague description (unlike @Carlton), but I am really interested in one.

Comment: @Wolf I meant same non-qualified name, of course. Comments can't show code well, but I've written an [example offsite](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c66cf030dd8215f). `Derived2` cannot hide `mustRemainBase`.

Comment: Thanks for doing the extra work, but I'm still not able to get the point. The relation between `Derived1` and `Base1` I'd consider bad style, because overriding (hiding) is not really helpful for non-virtual methods. I'm looking on [Columbo`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412622/2932052) and your answer as to understand if a combination of virtual+final+override is really useful or just a waist of time.

Comment: @Wolf I wouldn't call hiding bad style, it has very legitimate use cases, particularly in combination with template techniques.

Comment: However, it still doesn't prevent a derived class from hiding a final virtual by adding an extra parameter. I.e. a derived class can declare `void mustRemainBase(int = 0);` and hide the original.

Answer (score 6):

(Skip to the end to see the conclusion if you're in a hurry.)

Both `override` and `final` can appear only in declaration in a virtual function. And both key words can be used in the same function declaration, but whether it is useful to use them both depends on situations.

Take the following code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

struct B {
  virtual void f1() { cout << "B::f1() "; }
  virtual void f2() { cout << "B::f2() "; }
  virtual void f3() { cout << "B::f3() "; }
  virtual void f6() final { cout << "B::f6() "; }
  void f7() { cout << "B::f7() "; }
  void f8() { cout << "B::f8() "; }
  void f9() { cout << "B::f9() "; }
};

struct D : B {
  void f1() override { cout << "D::f1() "; }
  void f2() final { cout << "D::f2() "; }
  void f3() override final { cout << "D::f3() "; }  // need not have override
  // should have override, otherwise add new virtual function
  virtual void f4() final { cout << "D::f4() "; }
  //virtual void f5() override final;  // Error, no virtual function in base class
  //void f6(); // Error, override a final virtual function
  void f7() { cout << "D::f7() "; }
  virtual void f8() { cout << "D::f8() "; }
  //void f9() override;  // Error, override a nonvirtual function 
};

int main() {
  B b; D d;
  B *bp = &b, *bd = &d; D *dp = &d;
  bp->f1(); bp->f2(); bp->f3(); bp->f6(); bp->f7(); bp->f8(); bp->f9(); cout << endl;
  bd->f1(); bd->f2(); bd->f3(); bd->f6(); bd->f7(); bd->f8(); bd->f9(); cout << endl;
  dp->f1(); dp->f2(); dp->f3(); dp->f6(); dp->f7(); dp->f8(); dp->f9(); cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
B::f1() B::f2() B::f3() B::f6() B::f7() B::f8() B::f9()
D::f1() D::f2() D::f3() B::f6() B::f7() B::f8() B::f9()
D::f1() D::f2() D::f3() B::f6() D::f7() D::f8() B::f9()
```

1. Compare `f1()` and `f6()`. We know that `override` and `final` is indepent sematically.

   - `override` means the function is overriding a virtual function in its base class. See `f1()` and `f3()`.
   - `final` means the function cannot be overrided by its derived class. (But the function itself need not override a base class virtual function.) See `f6()` and `f4()`.
2. Compare `f2()` and `f3()`. We know that if a member function is declared without `virtual` and with `final`, it means that it already override a virtual function in base class. In this case, the key word `override` is redundant.
3. Compare `f4()` and `f5()`. We know that if a member function is declared with `virtual`and if it is not the *first* virtual function in inheritance hierarchy, then we should use `override` to specify the override relationship. Otherwise, we may accidentally add new virtual function in derived class.
4. Compare `f1()` and `f7()`. We know that any member function, not just virtual ones, can be overridden in derived class. What `virtual` specifies is *polymorphism*, which means the decision as to which function to run is delayed until run time instead of compile time. (This should be avoid in practice.)
5. Compare `f7()` and `f8()`. We know that we can even override a base class function and make it a new virtual one. (Which means any member function `f8()` of class derived from `D` will be virtual.) (This should be avoid in practice too.)
6. Compare `f7()` and `f9()`. We know that `override` can help us find the error when we want to override a virtual function in derived class while forgot to add key word `virtual` in base class.

**In conclusion**, the best practice in my own view is:

- *only* use `virtual` in declaration of the *first* virtual function in base class;
- always use `override` to specify override virtual function in derived class, unless `final` is also specified.

Answer (score 5):

The following code (with the `final` specifier) compiles. But compilation fails when `final` is replaced with `override final`. Thus `override final` conveys more information (and prevents compilation) than just `final`.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() final
    {
        std::cout << "in Derived foo\n";
    }
};
```

Essentially, `override final` says this method cannot be overridden in any derived class *and* this method overrides a virtual method in a base class. `final` alone doesn't specify the base class overriding part.

Comment: "final alone doesn't specify the base class overriding part."
Correct, but `void foo() final` does.

Answer (score 1):

No `final` does not necessarily imply `override`. In fact, you could declare a `virtual` function that you immediately declare `final` [see here](http://cpp.sh/6pfbg). The `final` keyword simply states that no derived `class` can create an override of this function.

The `override` keyword is important in that it enforces that you are indeed actually overriding a virtual function (instead of declaring a new unrelated one). See [this post regarding `override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/override-keyword-in-c)

So long story short, they each serve their own particular purpose, and it is often correct to use both.

Comment: Hmm, I wish that first example you posted wouldn't compile, because the way I see it declaring a virtual function and making it final in the same breath makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: cpp core guidelines say only use one https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override