# Is a vtable generated when a virtual function is immediately marked final?

Tags: c++, vtable

In this post: [Does final imply override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412412/does-final-imply-override), one of the answers showed that you can declare a function `virtual` AND `final` in the same declaration.  An example was given that this prevents derived classes from mistakenly declaring a function with the same signature, so as to avoid confusion about which function is actually being called.

My question is, will a compiler still generate a virtual table for such a function?  I would use this technique more often if I knew I wasn't incurring the vtable runtime overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes!

#### Speaking practically...

Firstly, virtual tables are not generated for functions; virtual tables are generated for *types* (with each instance having a pointer to the relevant virtual table).

Eliding the entire virtual table for a type just because none of its function members can be further overridden would cause a wealth of problems; for example, the resulting binary still needs to be able to *find* that `final` type when the instance is referenced through a pointer-to-`Base`.

The only time this may make sense is with a type with virtual members, which are all `final`, *and no base*:

```
/**
 * No members override (as there's no base)
 * and no members may be overridden (as they're
 * all `final`).
 */
struct Foo
{
   virtual void foo() final {}
};
```

Does a compiler elide the virtual table then? Maybe. Probably not; why implement an alternative, special-case set of semantics for an extreme corner scenario?

Actually, it would probably break anyway in the general case when you later add new virtual members further up the hierarchy:

```
/**
 * Well, this one needs a virtual table...
 * ...and it's probably going to want to
 * point out where Foo::foo() is...?
 */
struct Bar : Foo
{
   virtual void bar() {}
};
```

#### Speaking legally...

Besides all this, I can't see any evidence that eliding the virtual table would be ABI-compliant, at least not under [Itanium](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html):

> Each class that has virtual member functions or virtual bases has an associated set of virtual tables.

The `final` specifier is a C++ construct *only* with no ABI support, prohibiting such magic.

#### Speaking verifiably...

Ultimately, though, the only way to be *sure* is to actually examine the code that your compiler produces.

Comment: In the post I referenced, another user mentioned that `dynamic_cast` probably relies on virtual tables, so eliding the vtable would break `dynamic_cast` (for better or for worse).

Comment: I think the "no base" situation is similar to the "base, but not a polymorphic base" situation.