# Polymorphism? C++ vs Java

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism, comparison

Trying out polymorphism as a beginner. I think I am trying the same code in different languages, but the result is not the same :

C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:

    void whereami() {
        cout << "You're in A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    public:

    void whereami() {
        cout << "You're in B" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.whereami();
    b.whereami();
    A* c = new B();
    c->whereami();
    return 0;
}
```

Results :

```
You're in A
You're in B
You're in A
```

Java :

```
public class B extends A{

    void whereami() {
        System.out.println("You're in B");
    }

}

//and same for A without extends
//...


public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.whereami();
    B b = new B();
    b.whereami();
    A c = new B();
    c.whereami();
}
```

Results :

```
You're in A
You're in B
You're in B
```

Not sure if i'm doing something wrong, or this has to do with the languages themselves?

Comment: youre missing the `virtual` keyword in `whereami` in the 1st program...

Comment: @Reimeus: The OP also forgets to provide virtual destructor in Base class & write delete c; in the main() function.

Answer (score 10):

You need to read up about the `virtual` keyword for C++.  Without that qualifier, what you have are *member functions* in your objects. They don't follow the rules of polymorphism (dynamic binding). With the `virtual` qualifier you get methods, which use dynamic binding.  In Java, all instance functions are methods. You always get polymorphism.

Comment: With the virtual qualifier they're still member functions. C++ does not use the term "method". There are virtual member functions and non-virtual member functions. Terminology aside, though, the answer is correct.

Comment: I would never argue about C++ with Pete Becker.

Comment: I forgot to say that aside from the terminology, this answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Use "virtual functions".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:

    virtual void whereami() { // add keyword virtual here
        cout << "You're in A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    public:

    void whereami() {
        cout << "You're in B" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.whereami();
    b.whereami();
    A* c = new B();
    c->whereami();
    return 0;
}
```

In Java, all instance methods are virtual functions in default.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer but use [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for) keyword in derived classes to let compiler know that you are overriding.