# Why is override optional in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I understand the purpose of the [C++ override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/override-keyword-in-c), however am a bit confused by it's implementation compared to other higher level languages, where its use is required by default.

The [C++11 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final) describes it as a "technically identifier for declarator attribute" but does not elaborate as to why it is not simply a keyword for the language.

Comment: Adding `override` as keyword may break (old) codes which use it as identifier.

Comment: "[override gains] special meaning as attributes only when used in those specific trailing [attribute] contexts"

Comment: It's optional in part because many people think using it causes more complications than it resolves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is optional to maintain backwards compatibility with C++03. Making it non-optional would have broken all the code<sup>*</sup>.

Similarly, making `override` a keyword would have broken any code that used the name `override`.

---

<sup>OK, not literally *all* the code, but a lot of it.</sup>

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that backwards compatibility was such a high goal with C++11, but it is [literally the first design goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Design_goals) that the committee listed.

Comment: @nonathaj Yes, if it wasn't for that, C++ would be a great deal less awful :-)

Comment: Some compilers, such as Clang will detect that "you are using `override` in some of your code, so I'll warn you when it's missing in other places". In other words, it tries to enforce a consistent use of it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Off-topic but, to be honest, if it wasn't backward compatible, we'd still  be dealing with C++98-only legacy codebases for the next ten years...
Sure, new codebases would be less awful if we had "broken a few eggs", but I think what we have right now is the best compromise. Well, until we get perfect refactor tools that can update your codebase for free

Comment: @KABoissonneault Sure, and I wasn't trying to suggest that breaking backwards compatibility was ever a practical option. It just explains a lot of the weirdness in the language.

Comment: clang-modernize has an option to automatically add override in your code base.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, C++11 does not behave much differently from Java here (which is a typical example for one of the "other higher level languages" which you mention). A **wrong** `override` will be a compilation error, just like a wrong `@Override` in Java. A **missing** `override` will not be a compilation error, just like a missing `@Override` will not be a compilation error in Java.

The only real difference I can see is that Java tools have traditionally had better support to detect a missing `@Override`, and that Java users are traditionally encouraged to treat the corresponding warning as an error, whereas C++ compilers have been quite slow so far at adding warning options for missing `override`s.

But we're getting there; Clang now has `-Winconsistent-missing-override`, and newer GCCs have `-Wsuggest-override`. All you have to do is enable those warnings and treat them as errors, either forcibly by the compiler or simply by convention.

As for why it's not simply a keyword: backward compatibility with older code.