# Unable to access subclass methods from baseclass pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Not sure where my inheritance went wrong here, but I seem to be only able to access the methods of the baseclass when storing a subclass instance in a baseclass pointer:

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car():type("Car") {};
        Car(const char* t):type(t) {};
        void get_type() const { return this->type; };
    private:
        std::string type;
};

class Ford : public Car
{
    public:
        Ford():Car("Ford"), doors(4) {};
        Ford(int x):Car("Ford"), doors(x) {};
        void get_doors() const { return this->doors; };
    private:
        int doors;
};

int main()
{
    Car* c = nullptr;
    c = new Ford();
    c->get_doors(); // doesn't exist, only allows for get_type()
}
```

It's very likely it could be a misuse of the pointer. I'll admit that C++ is not my strong suit so I am trying to replicate a program written in Python that heavily uses inheritance but it's much less complicated than writing it in C++ since you don't have explicit use of Pointers and References (at the abstract level that is).

Comment: You could make `get_doors()` a pure virtual function in `Car` and override it in `Ford`. It can't return `void`, though.

Comment: @alterigel I thought I could use a `Car*` to point to any instance of a derived class from `Car`? That leaves no room for abstract class instantiation because there needs to be a single `Car` instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract class instantiation"? You can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `Car*` to point to any instance of a derived class from `Car`. But you are also limited to operations available to `Car`. (Because there is no guarantee that the thing your `Car*` points to supports `get_doors`. Imagine if the second line were `c = new Car();`.)

Comment: @FredLarson At runtime it will be unknown what type of `Car` subclass the user will create. So I would've thought that a `Car*` could point to any of the subclasses and allow access to not only `Car` members but that of the subclass as well?

Comment: That's what virtual functions are for, as I mentioned in my first comment. C++ is statically typed and does not have "duck typing" as Python does.

Comment: Try `static_cast<Ford *>(c)->get_doors();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python methods are *dynamic* - pure object-oriented in the nature of smalltalk.  You send an instance a message and if it can answer it, it does.

C++ is not like that.  It uses *static* types.  You have *declared* an object of type `Car*` so a) it can hold a pointer to any `Car` instance or instance of a subtype of `Car` and b) it can only be told to do what `Car`s can be told to do.

C++ also has *virtual* methods.  If a method, declared in `Car`, is virtual, then it can be *implemented* in a subclass of `Car` (e.g., in `Ford`).  Then that subclasses' implementation will be called when calling through a `Car` pointer.

Comment: I ended up using the `virutal` keyword and read the docs, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Addendum: This is done because C++ strives to make the program pay only for what the programmer asked for. Dynamic dispatch has a price, so in C++ you only pay that price if you ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what should happen. A `Car*` pointer only lets you see `Car` members. Try using a `Ford*` pointer instead to see Ford methods. To see why, consider you had another class deriving from `Car`:

```
class Honda : public Car {
    // no get_doors() here
    void honk();
};

... 

Car* c = new Honda();
c->get_doors(); // What should happen here???
```

On the other hand, if you want *every* `Car` to have its own number of doors, you could do a couple things:

You can declare a constant member in the base class:

```
class Car {
public:
    Car(int num_doors) : m_doors(num_doors) {}

    int get_doors() const { return m_doors; }
private:
    const int m_doors;
}

class Ford : public Car {
    Ford() : Car(4) {} // Now every ford has 4 doors
}

class Honda : public Car {
    Honda() : Car(5) {} // and every honda has 5
}
```

Another thing you can do is declare a virtual function in your base class, and override that in every subclass:

```
class Car {
public:
    virtual int num_doors() const = 0;
}

class Ford : public Car {
    int num_doors() const override { return 4; } // Now every ford has 4 doors
}

class Honda : public Car {
    int num_doors() const override { return 5; } // and every honda has 5
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the `virtual` keyword, but not `override`. Instead, in `Car` I declared `virtual get_doors() const {};` and then in `Ford` I declared `virtual get_doors() const {return this->doors;};`. Do I need to use `override`?

Comment: @pstatix: I recommend it. With `override`, if you make a mistake, you get a compile error. Without it, you get weird runtime behavior.

Comment: Indeed, while `override` is optional, it can only do good. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for