# How to save QPrinter drawing as QPixmap and set it as QIcon on window icon?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to save my version of analog_clock from qt examples as qpixamp and set it as window icon in ubuntu's taskbar.
Beside that i dont understand syntax below, why in argument is QPaintEvent pointer that i don't use and why do i have to override this method:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
```

Comment: Your question is (to me at least) very unclear.  Have you read the documentation for [`QWidget::paintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent)?

Comment: Hi, since you're new here on StackOverflow, please see [ask]. I presume you're referring to [_this_](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) analog clock example? The syntax is part of C++. The caller of `paintEvent` will pass it an argument, but we don't necessarily have to use it. Also see [What is the override keyword used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for). (Do consider reading online tutorials or [getting a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.)

Comment: Thank you for answers! But do you know answer to my first question?