# C++ more than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list when creating a header file

Tags: c++, linker-errors, header-files, forward-declaration, function-signature

Within my main file of my program I have the following declarations

```
int main()
{
    Customer c;
    Part p;
    Builder b;
    auto partsVec =  readpartFile();
    auto customerVec = readcustomerFile();
    auto builderVec = readbuilderFile();

    fexists("Parts.txt");
    complexity(c, partsVec);
    robotComplexity(partsVec,customerVec);
    writeFile(buildAttempt(b, complexity(c, partsVec), variability(customerVec, builderVec)));
}
```

My header file consists of the following

```
vector<Part> readpartFile();

vector<Customer> readcustomerFile();

vector<Builder> readbuilderFile();

float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);

void robotComplexity(vector<Part> vecB, vector<Customer> vecC);

double variability(const vector<Customer>& customerList, const vector<Builder>& builderList);

vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot);

void writeFile(vector<double> build);
```

All functions link up except for robotComplexity. My declaration of this function in main creates the following error.

more than one instance of overloaded function "robotComplexity" matches the argument list: -- function "robotComplexity(const std::vector> &parts, const std::vector> &customers)" -- function "robotComplexity(std::vector> vecB, std::vector> vecC)" -- argument types are: (std::vector>, std::vector>)

im not sure why im getting this error or how to resolve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mismatch between declaration in header and definition (which also serves as declaration):

- `void robotComplexity(vector<Part> vecB, vector<Customer> vecC);`
- `void robotComplexity(const vector<Part>& vecB, const vector<Customer>& vecC);`

Whereas parameter names can mismatch, types shouldn't, else, you create another overload.

Comment: ah okay that fixed it. How come making it a const made a different

Comment: `const std::vector<Part>&` and `std::vector<Part>` are different parameter type, the former is passed by const reference, the later is passed by value, so create a copy.

Comment: would it be possible if i talked to you through message?

Comment: Which is your questions?

Comment: When i run the code i get of errors. I can place them in a file for if you wish but there are a few that im unsure of

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4VCevJN8 here are all my errors. Alot of them are the same but for different aspects

Comment: You might probably ask another question. provide MCVE.

Comment: #include/forward declaration are missing.

Comment: my new errors https://pastebin.com/nJHKEExQ. I would but theres that many different types i dobut anyone would properly answer without each quesiton being in the title. Its an issue that ive had with stack from the start.

Comment: which includes are missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211995/discussion-between-jarod42-and-david-ling).

Comment: Go line by line. Start with #include <string>. Then move on to forward declarations or extern if needed, especially if something is only defined in a .cpp

Answer (score 1):

Jarod42's Answer is quite correct, but I want to add to it and provide a helpful methodology for future C++ coding.

When function signatures differ, the compiler will not complain. At best, you will receive a cryptic or hard to read linker error. This is especially common with inheritance and virtual functions. Even worse, sometimes they will work but actually call a new function with a different signature on a child class that doesn't match the base class.

There is a keyword in C++11 (and newer versions) called ***override***. Here is a more in depth discussion about what they keyword does: [OverrideKeywordLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for)

When this keyword is used on a virtual function, it becomes a **compile error** when the intended virtual function override does not match the base class function signature. Also, it gives a very human readable reason why the function override did not occur.

You mentioned in a comment that 'How come const made it different"? The answer is it all comes down to function signatures. Consider these two functions within a class.

```
class MyClass {
    int CalculateSomething();
    int CalculateSomething() const;
}
```

The const actually changes the function signature. They are considered two different functions. The bottom line is, always try to make errors compile errors over run-time errors. Use keywords that protect you from some few tribal C++ knowledge traps that exist.